# Azure Files share doesn't Work

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I've trying to create a share in Azure Files, but doesn't seem to work. I'm aware I have to create a new storage account, because it won't work with existing ones. So I have just deleted my empty storage account and re-created it.

Then I'm following the guide using Windows Azure PowerShell, but it gives the following error:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net'

Note that I've replaced my storage account name with 'storageaccountname' and the key with 'storageaccountkey'.

```
PS C:\System\AzureStorageFile> import-module .\AzureStorageFile.psd1

VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\System\AzureStorageFile\AzureStorageFile.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'TypesToProcess' from path 'C:\System\AzureStorageFile\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.types.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path 'C:\System\AzureStorageFile\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\System\AzureStorageFile\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzureStorageFileContent'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFileContent'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageContext'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Set-AzureStorageFileContent'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFileContent'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageContext'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageFileContent'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageContext'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'New-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageDirectory'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageFile'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Remove-AzureStorageShare'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Set-AzureStorageFileContent'.

PS C:\System\AzureStorageFile> $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext storageaccountname storageaccountkey

PS C:\System\AzureStorageFile> $s = New-AzureStorageShare data -Context $ctx

New-AzureStorageShare : The remote name could not be resolved: 'storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net'
At line:1 char:6
+ $s = New-AzureStorageShare data -Context $ctx
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Windo...ureStorageShare:NewAzureStorageShare) [New-AzureStorageShare], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NameResolutionFailure,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageShare
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Files is still in preview mode and is not automatically enabled.  Follow the steps at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx.  The first step asks you to go to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/preview/ to sign up for the Azure Files Preview feature.  Once you sign up for the preview you will have to wait until you get an email letting you know you are approved for the feature.

Comment: Thanks, I singed up and now "queued". Any clues how long does it take to enable it?

Comment: In the case that you run into errors caused by an ambiguous New-AzureStorageContext, you can explicitly reference the correct version by AzureStorageFile\New-AzureStorageContext. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/fb0887c3-d140-4b99-a72f-62b9d07a72e8/error-running-azurestoragefile-powershell-script?forum=azureautomation

Answer (score 3):

Is your storage account name you are using “'storageaccountname”?   If so, and you just created the storage account, then it appears the subscription you are using hasn’t been approved for the preview yet, which will result in the  'storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net' not resolving.

If you need access then follow the instructions here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

Note, we are slowly opening up access, so based on the very high demand the wait may be awhile.   You will receive email once your access is approved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question, but did you try already with creating a new one with a different name?

Comment: @techmike2kx, if you are just asking a question you should do it in the comments section, not as an answer.